# csv.writer.writerows takes iterator?

Tags: python, csv

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) for `writerows` states

> Write all the rows parameters (a list of row objects as described
>   above) to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current
>   dialect.

It suggests that `writerows` takes a list as a parameter.
But it can take an iterator, no problem

```
python -c 'import csv
> csv.writer(open("test.file.1", "w")).writerows(([x] for x in xrange(10)))
> '
cat test.file.1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

What gives? Does it convert the iterator to a list before writing out to the file, or, is the documentation misleading and it can actually write iterators to files without materializing them? The underlying code is in `C`; I can't make sense of it.

Comment: I'd say the documentation is just a bit sloppy. It's certainly convenient and within the expected use case of `writerows` to take an iterator.

Comment: @MarkRansom, good point - appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [sources for `csv`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ffbbd43d7342/Lib/csv.py) the `DictWriter` class *does* first create a list of rows to pass to the actual writer. See at [line 155](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ffbbd43d7342/Lib/csv.py#l155):

```
def writerows(self, rowdicts):
    rows = []
    for rowdict in rowdicts:
        rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
    return self.writer.writerows(rows)
```

The funny thing is that the `Writer` class, that is implemented in the `_csv` module (the C extension) does **not** need a list. We can see from the sources that it just obtains an iterable from the argument and calls `PyIter_Next`:

```
csv_writerows(WriterObj *self, PyObject *seqseq)
{
    PyObject *row_iter, *row_obj, *result;

    row_iter = PyObject_GetIter(seqseq);
    // [...]
    while ((row_obj = PyIter_Next(row_iter))) {
        result = csv_writerow(self, row_obj);
        // [...]
}
```

Note that there is no call to `PyList_*` methods nor any check for the `list` type at all.

In any case *both* `writerows` method do accept any iterable, however `DictWriter` is going to create an (unneccessary) intermediate list.
It is possible that in previous versions the `Writer` class did accept only `list`s and, as such, `DictWriter` had to do that conversion, however now it's outdated.

In current versions of python the `DictWriter.writerows` method could be reimplemented as:

```
def writerows(self, rowdicts):
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
    # or:
    #return self.writer.writerows(self._dict_to_list(row) for row in rowdicts)
```

which ought to have the same behaviour, except for avoid an unneccessary creation of the list of rows.

Comment: when you say "current versions of Python" in the context of  `map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))` I am guessing you mean 3+ since `map` returns a list in 2-series Python?

Comment: Ah, this is interesting. I'd checked the C code for `writerows` on the `Writer` type, but I didn't think to check the Python version in `DictWriter`. That should probably be fixed!

Comment: @1_CR Python3.0 was released *6 years* ago. Current version of python, for me, means python3.3+

Comment: @bakuriu, would that it were so. Industry adoption of 3.0 is virtually nonexistent. I can't get my company to go from 2.6 to 2.7 never mind 3

Answer (score 1):

Many functions in Python that are normally passed a list will in fact work with any kind of iterable object. This is because the contents of the list (or whatever) will be processed by a [`for` loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) (or perhaps the C equivalent in the case of a builtin function). A `for` loop always calls `iter` on the iterable it is going to act on, and [an iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterator#iterator-types) (such as the generator expression you're using) will always have an `__iter__` method that returns the iterator itself when `iter` is called on it.

This kind of design is known as ["duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), where any object that behaves in expected way (by having an `__iter__` method, in this case) will work just as well as any other. Other languages (that use static typing) would require any iterable object to inherit from some `Iterable` interface or class, and would require each function to declare that it expects an `Iterable` instance. Python is much less formal.

Mark Ransom, in his comment, is correct that the documentation of the `csv.writer.writerows` is a bit sloppy. It should probably say that it expects an iterable, rather than a list. I've reported this as [a minor documentation bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue23495).